# Define Docker container volume bindings in a configuration file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is there a way to define all the volume bindings either in the `Dockerfile` or another configuration file that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since volume bindings are used when you create a container, you can't define them in the `Dockerfile` (which is used to build your Docker *image*, not the *container*).

If you want a way to define the volume bindings without having to type them every time, you have the following options:

- Create a script that runs the `docker` command and includes all of the volume options.
- If you want to run more than one container, you can also use Docker Compose and define the volume bindings in the `docker-compose.yaml` file: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volumedriver

Out of the two, I prefer Docker Compose, since it includes lots of other cool functionality, e.g. allowing you to define the port bindings, having links between containers, etc. You can do all of that in a script as well, but as soon as you use more than one container at a time for the same application (e.g. a web server container talking to a database container), Docker Compose makes a lot of sense, since you have the configuration in one place, and you can start/stop all of your containers with one single command.

Comment: If you want to check out an example of how it is done in a docker-compose.yml file, you can take a look at my repo:  https://github.com/onlinespaces/docker-project-base

Comment: @nwinkler Just a follow up question, I do have a `Dockerfile`, Will it still remain while using a `docker-compose.yml` file ? How could these two files work together ?

Comment: You can (and should!) continue to use your existing `Dockerfile`. You can use it to build your image from the `docker-compose.yaml` file in the `build` section: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build